# Mejor alternativa a Workbench

Tags: mysql

Buenos dias. Pues eso, estoy comenzando con mysql con el manejador Workbench, pero me da la espina de ser un softwate anticuado, presiento que debe existir alguna alternativa mucho mejor.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: No es anticuado si miras en el [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-9.html) veras que la ultima versión salio el 7 del mes pasado.

Si no te gusta MySQL Workbench [aquí](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/awesome-mysql/#gui) tienes otras opciones